# how to select last 5 records from the my sql table

Tags: mysql

I am getting data from the server. I want that user may get only the last 5 records in the tables.

Here is the query I am currently using; it is not working:

```
 $query = mysql_query("
          SELECT 
          ml.PostID, 
          ml.UserID, 
          ml.PostDate, 
          ml.PostTime, 
          ml.PostCategory, 
          ml.PostSubCategory, 
          ml.PostComments, 
          cat.UserName
          FROM UserPosts AS ml
          LEFT JOIN UserNames cat 
          ON cat.UserID = ml.UserID 
          ORDERD BY DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Gives following error

Warning: **`mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getPosts.php on line 77`**

Comment: which column do you want to sort by?

Comment: @chetan i want to get all the data not any column

Comment: I mean you have ORDER BY DESC clause. But you have missed the column to sort

Comment: There isn't one AS on UserNames and it's ORDER BY no ORDERD by. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp

Comment: A SQL syntax error should be flagged before the rather useless PHP runtime error. Make sure you have the appropriate settings turned on in your driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT ml.PostID, 
       ml.UserID, 
       ml.PostDate, 
       ml.PostTime, 
       ml.PostCategory, 
       ml.PostSubCategory, 
       ml.PostComments, 
       cat.UserName
FROM UserPosts AS ml
LEFT JOIN UserNames cat 
      ON cat.UserID = ml.UserID 
ORDER BY ml.PostTime DESC LIMIT 5';

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

add column name in order by clause

```
SELECT ml.PostID, 
       ml.UserID, 
       ml.PostDate, 
       ml.PostTime, 
       ml.PostCategory, 
       ml.PostSubCategory, 
       ml.PostComments, 
       cat.UserName
FROM UserPosts AS ml
LEFT JOIN UserNames cat 
ON cat.UserID = ml.UserID 
ORDER BY ml.PostComments DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: replace columnName with one of the column

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT ml.PostID, ml.UserID, ml.PostDate, ml.PostTime, ml.PostCategory, ml.PostSubCategory, ml.PostComments, cat.UserName
FROM UserPosts AS ml
LEFT JOIN UserNames cat ON cat.UserID = ml.UserID ORDERD BY ml.PostTime desc DESC LIMIT 5");

Comment: same error $query = mysql_query("SELECT ml.PostID, ml.UserID, ml.PostDate, ml.PostTime, ml.PostCategory, ml.PostSubCategory, ml.PostComments, cat.UserName
FROM UserPosts AS ml
LEFT JOIN UserNames cat ON cat.UserID = ml.UserID ORDER BY ml.PostComments desc
DESC LIMIT 5 ");

Comment: @JawAli why do u have 2 `desc`? it should be just `ORDER BY ml.PostComments DESC`